# Does anyone know what's written on the Funtom's Bitter Rabbit ear?

Tags: black-butler

I am making a plush toy of *Funtom's Bitter Rabbit* from *Kuroshitsuji (Black Butler)* and noticed there's a tag on one of the ears, but I couldn't find what was written on it.

What is it?

Comment: From what I can tell the bunny your referring to is called `Phantom's beter rabbit` and is introduced on page 5 panel 2 of Chapter 2 referenced here. http://www.mangahere.co/manga/kuroshitsuji/v01/c002/5.html

Comment: I did on accident write bitter bunny  instead of bitter rabbit, but I don't think it's called "beter bunny". Well, maybe in the manga it is. But that still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to answer it. I was simply adding context and a reference to what you were asking about to make it easier for the community to look into. I could have just edited your question but given that my context was short I figured it'd be better as a comment

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official merchandise on Square Enix store](http://store.jp.square-enix.com/item/4988601533331.html),

[image: Bitter Rabbit plushie]

it's **Funtom.Co[...]**. There are 2 possibilities:

1. FUNTOM.COMPANY
2. FUNTOM.CORPORATION

Considering the rest of the spaces, I'd believe it's **FUNTOM.CORPORATION** since for half of the tag's length, `FUNTOM.CO` takes 9 characters, and `RPORATION` also takes 9 characters.

---

<sup>There's a Wikia entry on [Funtom Corporation](http://kuroshitsuji.wikia.com/wiki/Funtom_Corporation), but I'm not sure if it's the official translation, since the name in Japanese is ファントム社【しゃ】, with [社](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A4%BE#Japanese) usually translated as *company*.</sup>

Comment: Nice research! Have an upvote!